# Programming methods design phase assignment

Tags: oop

Hey, i have an assignment (NCC) which deals with the design phase. The Scenario is that you have four soccer divisions (divisions 1,2,3 and 4) which consist of 22 teams each and hence each team plays 42 games (home and away). The concept is similar to the barclays premier league whereby ranking is based on points or else goal difference or else goals scored by team. The difference is that the top 2 teams are promoted and the bottom 2 are relegated and this includes Div 1 and Div 4 as the top 2 of Div1 are promoted to the national league which is above division 1 regional league and bottom 2 of Div4 are relegated to the local league below Division 4 regional league. Hence there are 3 total leagues and 4 divisions in the regional league (which has 22 teams each). Now the referee has to add the result of the match and thus automatic tables have to be generated now,
There are two reports

1. League Tables for 4 divisions
2. List of all results for any chosen team during the season by date it was played on

There are a couple of things to be done... i know its gonna be terrible to make everything but atleast explain to me how i should go about drawing these and what things i should include (generally)

- Logical Data Structure Diagram (DSD) for each report
- Preliminary Program Structure (PSD) for each report
- Detailed Program Specification for each report
- Flowchart for each report

There are other things but i think our teacher will give us clear "clues" for it
Thanks a lot

---

Update - Project so far:

[DSD http://www.freewebtown.com/caesar3/images/DSD.jpg](http://www.freewebtown.com/caesar3/images/DSD.jpg)

Data Structure Diagram

[PSD http://www.freewebtown.com/caesar3/images/PSD.jpg](http://www.freewebtown.com/caesar3/images/PSD.jpg)

Preliminary Program Structure

Comment: We are not going to do your homework/assignment for you.

Comment: You are expected to try it yourself first. If you show us how far you got on your own, we will help fixing/improving it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that since it is a diagram i will need to post an image which i cannot do at the moment. I have tried to give an external link which links to the image, hope u can check it out.
I have just drawn a DSD and PSD, am not sure how to differentiate it but also i have no idea how to come about with the Detailed Program Specification. (this is only report 1)
http://www.freewebtown.com/caesar3/project.html

Comment: I added your diagrams as pictures to the post.

Answer (score 0):

This is hte first time I see a DSD or PSD, so take my answer with a grain of salt :-)

To me the DSD looks OK except that I am not sure about the changes. I understand that promotions / demotions take place once a year. So if this report is generated yearly, it makes sense to include the promotions & demotions indeed (however there is no point to mention "remain" - if a team has not been promoted neither demoted, then it obviously remains in the same division / league). But if the report is regenerated regularly around the year, there are no changes most of the time - maybe it would make sense to mention in the team details if this team is a newbie in this division.

The PSD looks fine to me.

Now starting from the DSD, you could go into the details to get a Detailed Program Specification. Have a look at each element in the diagram and write down in a few words what exactly you imagine this include, how this would look in the report. You may do a couple of rounds going through the report and refining your ideas. If there is some specific format / structure for the Detailed Program Specification, after the first round you can start massaging your ideas into the requested format.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and suggestion. The thing is that we usually draw some circles on the header and footer and put numbers and then have a key whereby the numbers have some sort of meaning (not description just meaning). The body remains the same but i am not sure how to do it properly. Is there a tutorial online where I can get the way these things are done because I have not seen anything in our NCC textbook.